# Twilio Client JS roster event

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm using Twilio Client JS 1.2, and am seeing an 'eventType' of 'roster' com ing in, which seems handy, but I can't figure out how to access it.  (seeing this via 'debug:true').

```
[Log] Object (twilio.min.js, line 58)
EventType: "roster"
Roster: Array[1]
0: "admin"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
Roster_v2: Array[1]
0: Object
Available: true
From: "admin"
Meta: Object
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

The 'demo' way of getting this info is via 'presence' events, which I can't seem to get working right (and only seem to show presence info of other people).

Is the 'roster' event info something that's from a previous version and is to be deprecated?  Is this a new event that a future library will support?

The docs and the functionality of the library seem somewhat out of sync, but I may be reading things completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For presence I use it as follows,

```
Twilio.Device.presence(softPhonePresence);

function softPhonePresence(presenceEvent)
    {            
        // Called for each available client when this device becomes ready
        // and every time another client's availability changes.
        //presenceEvent.from // => name of client whose availability changed
        //presenceEvent.available // => true or false
    }
```

the part that you are explaining that you only get events from other people's presence events from what I know is correct. However if you want to know if "this" client is connected, you can use the following event, which will tell you that you are online.

```
Twilio.Device.ready(softPhoneReady);
function softPhoneReady(device)
    {           
        console.log("softPhoneReady");
        // Could be called multiple times if network drops and comes back.
        // When the TOKEN allows incoming connections, this is called when
        // the incoming channel is open.
    }
```

For offline, I use this

```
Twilio.Device.offline(softPhoneOffline);
function softPhoneOffline(device)
    {
        // Called on network connection lost.
    }
```

Using the last two code snippets, you could easily set a variable that will tell you that you are online or offline.

I hope this helps

Louis